# How can I configure FreeRADIUS to query multiple base DNs?

Tags: ldap, google-workspace, freeradius

We are looking to migrate our RADIUS authentication over to a client's Google Workspace. We currently have an instance of FreeRADIUS running and functioning properly, with users able to connect using their Google credentials.

However, we've run into a bit of a snag as users' primary names within the Google Workspace can have four possible domains - this is the result of a merger that occurred some time ago. So for example, a given user's primary email address might be any of the following:

- user@example1.com
- user@example2.com
- user@example3.com
- user@example4.com

Everybody has an alias at example1.com as part of a larger rebranding, but primary usernames have yet to transition for compatibility reasons.

I'm wondering if there is a way to have FreeRADIUS query multiple base DNs if the first DN turns up no results. Something like this:

- Query DC=example1,DC=com.
- If not found, query DC=example2,DC=com.
- etc
- etc

I've already tried having it query DC=com, that failed rather predictably.
The actual domain of the user is unimportant as everyone is getting more or less the same access - this is just a matter of finding the user in the correct tree.

Answer (score 1):

You could leave FreeRADIUS setup with the Google Workspace Primary Domain,

```
base_dn = 'dc=example,dc=com'
```

Then add a matching Primary Domain alias for users in the Secondary Domain.

| Username | Alias | RADIUS Accepts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user1@example.com | N/A | user1, user1@example.com |
| user2@contoso.com | user2@example.com | user2, user2@example.com |